# Candidates in an exam

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

443 candidates enter the exam hall. There are 20 rows of seats I'm the hall. Each row has 25 seats. At least how many rows have an equal number of candidates.

My attempt
Seat 25 in the first row  24 in the second and so on...but I cannot find the worst case scenario.

Comment: At least 1 row have an equal number of candidates.

Comment: It's a little unclear (to me) what you're asking for, so let me rephrase what I think the problem is:  We want a sequence of integers $0\le r_1\le r_2\le\cdots\le r_{20}\le25$ such that $r_1+r_2+\cdots+r_{20}=443$ which *minimizes* the number of times $r_i=r_{i+1}$.  Is that right?

Comment: Using your way, you are trying to find a case where no two rows have the same number of candidates. At most there would accommodate $25+24+23+\cdots + 6$ candidates. So strictly more than $1$ row have the equal number of candidates.

Comment: @BarryCipra, I think perhaps we're trying to minimize the value of $j$ such that there is a run of $j$ values $r_i = \cdots = r_{i+j-1}$ in the sorted list and no run of $j+1$ values.

Comment: @DavidK, that's exactly why I said it was unclear what the OP is asking for -- there are competing interpretations.

Comment: @peterwhy, was your comment addressed to me?  If so, I didn't make myself clear.  I'm not trying to make all the interior inequalities strict; in effect I'm just trying to maximize the number that are strict.

Comment: @BarryCipra Sorry, I was replying novak. I cannot edit to add his name now...

Comment: @peterwhy, that's OK.  I'll leave my reply up, since maybe it does add a little clarity anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a_1,a_2\dots a_{20}$ be non-negative integers such that $a_1+a_2+\dots a_{20}=443$. Denote by $s$ the size of the largest subset of the $a$'s which all have the same value. I think we want to minimize this.

We shall prove it is three. To show it is more than two we notice that with $s=2$ the maximum sum would be achieved with

$a_1=a_{11}=16,a_2=a_{12}=17\dots a_3=a_{3}=18 \dots a_{10}=a_{20}=25$

Then the sum of the $a$'s would be $2\frac{10(41)}{2}=410$.

We now prove with $s=3$ it is obtainable, to see this we take the numbers from $20$ to $25$ three times (these are $6\times 3=18$ numbers). This allready adds up to $3\frac{45(6)}{2}=405$. For the remaining $38$ we must use three numbers, we use the number $13$ two times and the number $12$ once. Therefore it is possible for $s$ to be three.

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain how you decided to take numbers 3 at a time?

Comment: 3 is the correct answer @jorgefernandez

Comment: Well, it seemed like the number was going to be small, so I tries with two but it didn't work. So I tried with three and it did!

Answer (score 2):

We have to distribute $500-443=57$ balls into $20$ containers such that the contents of the containers are as different as possible. Having two containers each with $0$, $1$, $\ldots$, $9$ balls requires $90$ balls. Therefore it is impossible to do it with no three containers getting an equal number of balls.

We now try it with three containers each getting $0$, $1$, $\ldots$ balls. It turns out that we need $3(0+1+\ldots+5)=45$ balls to serve $18$ of the $20$ containers, and that there are just $2\cdot 6$ balls left to  put into the last two containers.

Comment: One very nice thing about this answer is it looks at how you distribute the _empty seats_, which is much easier to account for than how you deal with the occupied seats.